# The correct practice to implement these relationships in django models

Tags: python, django, database-design

I am designing my database, and want to know if the relationships I am implementing are the best practice or not.

The aim is that one person can own multiple places, and multiple people can even book a single place at different times. One place can have multiple bookings.

So I am using this code:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ban = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )

class Bookings(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    booker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The expected output is a secure way to implement the relationships. Currently, they are working when I tested them in the shell, with one or two places / users, but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: If you are worried that your code is working well, you can write a test code and apply your code to various situations. [Django test doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/) will help you.

Comment: In general, use *singular* for model classes: `Booking` not `Bookings`. The object you describe is a single booking, not a bunch of bookings. That way the relationships feel more natural. Like you named `Place` and `User`. Also add `related_name` attributes to your `ForeignKey` fields, to name the reverse relationship. E.g. instead of `user.booking_set.all()` you would be able to say `user.bookings` if you set `related_name="bookings"`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the good way of implementing it, with an [n-to-n relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/).

> NB: You should consider replacing `date = models.CharField(max_length=100)` by a [DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield)
>
> If you want safety with your data you could replace `on_delete=models.CASCADE` by safer modes, like `on_delete=models.PROTECT`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation so i can't upvote but thanks

Comment: No problem. But if that answered your question, could you mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Your relationships are correct, but the current `Booking` model allows for multiple reservations of a same place at the same time. You'd need at least a unique constraint on `(place, date)`. Also as olinox mentionned you definitly want a `DateField` (or `DatetimeField`) for `Booking.date`:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    booker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [("date", "place")]
```

Also, use the contrib.auth `User` model or a compatible `AbstractUser` - safe authentication is not that trivial so better to use tested, proven, maintained code.